# How to know where javascript calls redirect?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, virus

So, I have wordpress site that was infected by javascript virus, that calls redirect to another site. There is a set of js files.
How to know where javascript calls redirect? What browser tools can use for this?

Comment: Try putting your browser in "no javascript" mode, and then navigate to and inspect the source code of your website to see where/what malicious javascript got injected.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem like this you might want to look into your .htaccess file in the root directory. Some code was injected that made the page reload if the site was loaded from referring url such as google, yahoo, bing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do. 
You can go though javascripts files content which should be encrypted basically using **base64_encode** so you might get it bit hard to understand code pattern.

You can use the `Event Listener Breakpoint -> Load - unload` and then when it breaks in the 3rd party library, right click and select Blackbox Script. The next time you play through the code, it should only break in your own code (assuming there are no other 3rd party libraries to blackbox).

Another option is to go to the `Network tab and check the Preserve Log checkbox`. This will persist all requests between page loads/navigation, so that you will be able to find the network request

For Firefox check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

[image]